# Element tree: .tail() always returns NONE

Tags: elementtree

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(input), parser)

for target in tree.findall("//tr[@class='error']"):
print target.tail
```

I want to execute the code above on this an fetch everything after 
`trclass="error"id="Testcase_5">`

```
 <tr class="error" id="Testcase_5"><td><a href="blabla">Hello</a></td><td>test</td><td>test</td>    <td>test</td><td>Failed</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

However all I get is NONE

Answer (score 0):

`tail`, by definition from `lxml`, is:

> the text that directly follows the element, up to the next element in the XML tree

Since your `tr` class does not have any text beyond the `<tr> .... </tr>` and we just have one element, it returns `None`.

Let's say the `input` is:

```
'<tr class="error" id="Testcase_5"><td><a href="blabla">Hello</a></td><td>test</td><td>test</td>    <td>test</td><td>Failed</td><td></td><td></td></tr>i am the tail'
```

then the output would be `i am the tail`

---

Coming back to your question, if you want to extract all the text within the `<tr>` node you could do something like this:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(input), parser)

for target in tree.findall(".//tr[@class='error']"):
    #print target.tail
    print target.xpath("//text()")
```

This will print:

```
['Hello', 'test', 'test', '    ', 'test', 'Failed']
```

Check [lxml docs](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text)